# Unable to decode stream

Tags: android, filenotfoundexception

I want to save an image into Bitmap by using the absolute path of the image file, below is my code:

```
Log.d("PhotoPath", selected.getImagePath());
File file = new File(selected.getImagePath());
if(file.exists())
{
    Log.d("File", "Exist");
    Bitmap d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selected.getImagePath()).getBitmap();
    int nh = (int) (d.getHeight() * (512.0 / d.getWidth()));
    Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(d, 512, nh, true);
    iv_Photo.setImageBitmap(scaled);
}
else
    Log.d("File", "Not exist");
```

Below is my output including the exception:

```
D/PhotoPath: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/POEMS/JPEG_20161214_170251_1637243168.jpg
D/File: Exist
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/POEMS/JPEG_20161214_170251_1637243168.jpg (Permission denied)
W/BitmapDrawable: BitmapDrawable cannot decode /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/POEMS/JPEG_20161214_170251_1637243168.jpg
```

What is the problem? I did add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Manifest.

Comment: cannot decode - this error is because if you try to decode a file you should load the file.getAbsolutePath() , which should give android something like file:/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/POEMS/JPEG_20161214_170251_1637243168.jpg , so here the file:/ is missing so it wont decode  image

Comment: Have you noticed this - `Permission denied`

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> you should specify this permission as well.

Comment: @HourGlass it gives me No such file or directory if I add "file:" into the path

Comment: so now you are not getting permission denied error? did you add read_external_Storage permission as well ? if you are not getting permission denied error now. try using the pervious path you have

Comment: @MonishKamble I noticed that, but how to solve? I did include permission

Comment: If you are targeting API 23, you have to request permissions at Runtime. Check this out - https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: @HourGlass exactly, no more `Permission denied`, but now `No such file or directory`

Comment: @MonishKamble thank you, the problem was I didn't request permission at Runtime.

Comment: For debugging, grant the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission manually from Settings. If the error resolves, you have to implement Runtime Permissions. Else, post the error log.

Comment: I think the way you are directly trying to convert a bitmap a bitmap as drawable is leading you to this error. First decode the file as bitmap Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getUri.toString(),null); you can also scaled down bitmap using BitmapFactory.options and pass it to while decode.File(file_path,(BitmapFactory )option). This will give you a scaled bitmap

Answer (score -1):

Please see below here, you need to decode file path then you will get bitmap.

```
Log.d("PhotoPath", selected.getImagePath());
File file = new File(selected.getImagePath());
if(file.exists())
{
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
else
    Log.d("File", "Not exist");
```

Comment: The problem is due to Runtime Permissions as seen in logcat messages.

Comment: please set target version to 21 then run your application.

Comment: Why to lower the target version? That is not a solution. The solution is to implement Runtime Permissions.

Comment: Then you need to implement version condition for taking permission to above these code then on the permission access block you can do this. Else i already said to you what you need to do.

Comment: As commented by the OP, the problem was due to Runtime Permissions. Nothing wrong with the image decoding code. This is not a valid answer.

Comment: I suggest you for permission you should implement this.. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162152/storage-permission-error-in-marshmallow)