# Unable to decode stream: android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, pusher, chatkit

I've recently tried implementing Pusher's Chatkit into my android app along with some Kotlin plugins and am now running into this error that I cannot resolve.

`E/Drawable: Unable to decode stream: android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.`

the error I'm getting right below it is:

`E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE`

Which is through throwing me for a loop because my internet is working fine although a couple lines further down, I get:

```
W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds.
    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
Process 15216 terminated.
```

Note: I've started to get this error above about not having a good connection ever since I started working more at cafes instead of at home since I needed to get out. In order to work offline, firebase asked me to opt into an [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline) I've been getting this notification of not being able to connect ever since.

I am following along to the getting started page [here](https://pusher.com/docs/chatkit/getting_started/android) and have completed up to the end of the "Displaying Messages" section however when I go to the activity, it just stalls and blanks out. I have been searching StackO and the rest of the web for the past 2 days to try to resolve the conflict to no avail. All of the similar posts I have looked at dont seem to resolve the issue.

[similarPost#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216176/unable-to-decode-stream) but I'm not trying to save to a bitmap

Here is the entire stack trace:

```
E/Drawable: Unable to decode stream: android.graphics.ImageDecoder$DecodeException: Failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'Input contained an error.
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Token retrieval failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE
W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller: Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
I/ghborsbookshel: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/chatty: uid=10086(com.example.android_myneighborsbookshelf) AsyncTask #2 identical 1 line
I/ghborsbookshel: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
V/NativeCrypto: Registering com/google/android/gms/org/conscrypt/NativeCrypto's 286 native methods...
W/ghborsbookshel: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->getCurveName()Ljava/lang/String; (light greylist, reflection)
I/ProviderInstaller: Installed default security provider GmsCore_OpenSSL
W/Firestore: (21.3.0) [OnlineStateTracker]: Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Backend didn't respond within 10 seconds

    This typically indicates that your device does not have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to the backend.
Process 15216 terminated.
```

Comment: Just to confirm, is this a widespread issue? Does it occur on multiple devices with different Internet connections?

Comment: @clownba0t so far this is happening as I'm using the emulator(Pixel API 28) on my MacBook laptop. I havent test other devices yet.

Comment: Try on some other devices, if you can. Also, it's always worth making sure that the date and time are correct on the device - sometimes differences can cause issues with SSL (although usually that's an immediate handshake error rather than timing out ...)

Answer (score 7):

It seems to have fixed itself except for the unable to decode stream error however it doesn't crash, it just shows up in the log.

I checked for updates, cleaned, rebuild, invalidated caches and restarted, and shut down my emulator. I also restarted my computer completely 2x and that seems to have fixed it.